# CSS family tree alignment issues with name length

Tags: html, css

I started with the experimental multi-parent version of the CSS3 Family Tree: http://thecodeplayer.com/experiment/css3-family-tree/2

However I am having some **alignment issues** with multiple parents (partners in a family tree), which seem to be caused by the length of the text in boxes. If two boxes have the same length text they line up, otherwise the longer one is higher, and the difference in height is proportional to the difference in length.

Also, any child on there own seems to float off to the left rather than sitting centrally as they should. **EDIT: THIS PART HAS BEEN ANSWERED**

Examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/7g7fz2tL/5/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 65px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}
/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}
/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(1px);
  transform: translateX(1px);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li a+a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.tree li a+a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  top: 50%;
  left: -26px;
  width: 25px;
}
/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover~ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/

.tree li a:hover~ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover~ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover~ul::before,
.tree li a:hover~ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}

.tree li a {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.tree > ul > li > ul:before {
  top: -40px;
}
.tree ul li.great-grandchild {
    float: none;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Root</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child with name</a>
          <a href="#">Child with name</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grandchild with name</a>
              <a href="#">Grandchild with longer name</a>
              <ul>
                <li class="great-grandchild">
                  <a href="#">Great Grandchild</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grandchild with name</a>
              <a href="#">Grandchild with much longer name</a>
              <ul>
                <li class="great-grandchild">
                  <a href="#">Great Grandchild</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas what could be causing this/how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the missing vertical alignment.

http://jsfiddle.net/7g7fz2tL/6/

```
.tree li a {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  vertical-align: top; /*THIS*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add a class to the great grandchildren and set float to none like so:

```
ul li.great-grandchild {
    float:none;
}
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/aex7gsq4/) is a link to a working example